# Encountering this error when running live server through vscode, anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, liveserver

This error pops up when I run live server through chrome from vscode, I'm not sure how to proceed. HTML and CSS works but JavaScript doesn't run at all.

```
// <![CDATA[  <-- For SVG support
if ('WebSocket' in window) {
    (function () {
        function refreshCSS() {
            var sheets = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("link"));
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; ++i) {
                var elem = sheets[i];
                var parent = elem.parentElement || head;
                parent.removeChild(elem);
                var rel = elem.rel;
                if (elem.href && typeof rel != "string" || rel.length == 0 || rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet") {
                    var url = elem.href.replace(/(&|\?)_cacheOverride=\d+/, '');
                    elem.href = url + (url.indexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?') + '_cacheOverride=' + (new Date().valueOf());
                }
                parent.appendChild(elem);
            }
        }
        var protocol = window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://';
        var address = protocol + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/ws';
        var socket = new WebSocket(address);
        socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
            if (msg.data == 'reload') window.location.reload();
            else if (msg.data == 'refreshcss') refreshCSS();
        };
        if (sessionStorage && !sessionStorage.getItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer')) {
            console.log('Live reload enabled.');
            sessionStorage.setItem('IsThisFirstTime_Log_From_LiveServer', true);
        }
    })();
}
else {
    console.error('Upgrade your browser. This Browser is NOT supported WebSocket for Live-Reloading.');
}
// ]]>
```

Comment: which error? the error in the `console.error` at the bottom of the code? Is the error displayed in the browser developer tools console? What do you mean by running a live server **through** chrome?

Comment: @Bravo sorry that was worded very poorly on my part, the error is displayed in chrome when I inspect the source. I’m also using vscode and run the live server through that.

Comment: so, in chrome, `if ('WebSocket' in window)` is false?

Comment: To be honest, I don’t know. I’m still very intermediate when it comes to JavaScript. But yes whenever I inspect the page source in chrome that error populates every time.